# libexif make optional

Tags: c, optional-parameters, libexif

I use libexif in my C/gtk+ application. But i want to make it optional. What must i to write in my configure file for to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check conditional compilation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Conditional-Sources.html). And define the calls under those flags.